# This unique character is rendered as two characters in Sublime. Why?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, sublimetext2

This single character :

ਠਂ

gives two characters when copied/pasted into Sublime Text 2 (Windows 7 here), in a document saved with UTF-8. Why?

I can imagine it's an encoding problem, but which one?

[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/663. Note that I cannot reproduce this on OS X 10.12 w/ ST2 or ST3 by copying ਠਂ from this page and pasting it (that works).

Comment: I can repro in Sublime Text Build 3114 on Win7.